# change user's name in navigation menu when user logs in

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation menu and in the header of it there is a textView that shows the user name when he/she logs into the application(like Gmail app).

Unfortunately when the user logs in the LogInActivity and goes back to the MainActivity the textView doesn't change and you have to restart the app to change the text.
(I used sharedPreferences to save the user name)

How can i solve this problem??

Comment: Can we see how you did that.. only the setting text

Comment: In which activity textview is and how you send data from one activity to another activity ? Best will be to store values like username in Application class so that it is available everywhere in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code below to get the navigation view and replace "Your Text Here" with your username

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView navUsername = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.navUsername);
navUsername.setText("Your Text Here");
```

This worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

When you come back to **MainActivity**, *the textview must be updated.*
So you can do that in **onResume() of the MainActivity**.

> Take the user's name and put it in the textview of your navigation
>   drawer.

I think you have a **abstract activity** that manages the navigation drawer ?
You must update your navigation drawer in **onResume() of the abstract activity**, in this case in all activity the name will be updated when the activity come back in front.

Answer (score -1):

First you can use `sharedPreferense` for example every time you login, you save dates and later you can display it on the `navigationDrawer` or  you can use `sqlite` DB to store your data and later retrieve it and use `setText()` to display it.